# add &_ after cournt 40 times in some string

Tags: regex, split, count, base64, notepad++

i have this base64 string i need to add ( &_ ) every 40 letter

> 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

i mean like this  c3ViIG1zZ19ib3ggKHRleHQp &_ eCh0ZXh0ICwzKzY0LCAiRXhlbXBs
how to do that with nodtepad++

Comment: Sounds like a task that can be easily done with a small script ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Find: `.{40}`
- Replace: `$0 &_[space]`

Then click on "Replace All".

The `.` is called wildcard, and matches any character.
`$0` means that you are replacing the 40 character with the whole matching (i.e. with themselves). After `$0` you add `[space]&_[space]` to getwhat you want.

[image: Notepad++ screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

i write it also in vb.net and this is the code

```
Sub main()
    Dim aa As String = "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"

    Dim bb As String = aa.Length

    For i As Integer = 40 To bb Step +41
        aa = aa.Insert(i, " &_ ")
    Next
    MsgBox(aa)


End Sub
```